# Using if statement with database in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
veri = sqlite3.connect('IBCKayıt')
v = veri.cursor()

v.execute("SELECT numsıra FROM kayıtlar WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM kayıtlar WHERE numsıra)")
record = v.fetchall()

if numaraentry.get() in record:
    messagebox.showinfo("UYARI","Bu IBC Zaten Var")

if numaraentry.get() not in record:
    v.execute("INSERT INTO kayıtlar VALUES (:numsıra, :koruyucutarih, :numunedurumm, :kullandurumm)",
        {'numsıra':numaraentry.get(),
         'koruyucutarih':tarıhgırıs,
         'numunedurumm':secılmıs1.get(),
         'kullandurumm':secılmıs.get()
        })
    messagebox.showinfo("UYARI","Kayıt İşlemi Başarılı.")


veri.commit()
veri.close()
```

I want it to give a warning when the same data is entered, but when I enter the same data, it does not give a warning. What do you think is the solution?

-I'm new to the form, I guess I don't know how to open a topic, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query doesn't make much sense; you'll want to use `WHERE` there.

Something like

```
veri = sqlite3.connect("IBCKayıt")

num = numaraentry.num()

v = veri.cursor()

v.execute("SELECT numsıra FROM kayıtlar WHERE numsıra = ? LIMIT 1", (num,))
records = v.fetchall()

if records:  # had a matching row, show error
    messagebox.showinfo("UYARI", "Bu IBC Zaten Var")
else:
    v.execute(
        "INSERT INTO kayıtlar VALUES (:numsıra, :koruyucutarih, :numunedurumm, :kullandurumm)",
        {
            "numsıra": num,
            "koruyucutarih": tarıhgırıs,
            "numunedurumm": secılmıs1.num(),
            "kullandurumm": secılmıs.num(),
        },
    )
    veri.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo("UYARI", "Kayıt İşlemi Başarılı.")

veri.close()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I made some edits on the code you sent and it is working now. Thanks a lot